# VBA : combine range with row insert and merging

Tags: excel, vba

here you see the lines for merging certain cells when a row is inserted.

```
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.row, "H"), Cells(ActiveCell.row, "L")).mergeCells = True
Range("H" & ActiveCell.row + 1).Resize(, 5).Merge
```

i would like to add a range value but i can't find how or where to add it in the existing code.
the range in the excel is **"H3752":"L4990"**, so only in that range the cells are to be merged, and not in the entire worksheet.

kinds regards.

Comment: Not sure I get you, but `ActiveCell.row` is the key here, use 3752 and 4990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells(Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count, Target.Item(1, 1).Column).ID = Target.Address
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Item(1, 1).ID <> "" Then
        'Code for if row is deleted
    Else
        'Code for if row is inserted
        If Target.Row >= 3752 And Target.Row <= 4990 Then
           Range(Cells(Target.Row, "H"), Cells(Target.Row, "L")).MergeCells = True
           Range("H" & Target.Row + 1).Resize(, 5).Merge
        End If
    End If
    Target.Item(1, 1).ID = ""
    Cells(Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count, Target.Item(1, 1).Column).ID = Target.Address
End Sub
```

To change what rows you are looking at you can change this line: `If Target.Row >= 3752 And Target.Row <= 4990 Then`  If you are trying to change the columns you can change this letters in this section:

```
Range(Cells(Target.Row, "H"), Cells(Target.Row, "L")).MergeCells = True
Range("H" & Target.Row + 1).Resize(, 5).Merge
```

Answer (score 0):

works like a charm! but if i secure the excel file i do get an error now :  "1004 while executing : error defined by the application or object"

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by when you secure the excel file?  I assume you mean you are protecting the worksheet?  If that is the case then you just need to unlock the sheet at the start of your code and then relock it at the end.  That can be done using `Sheets(yourSheetName).unprotect password:=yourPassword` and `Sheets(yourSheetName).protect password:=yourPassword`

Comment: yes it's protecting the file, and thank you i've got everything working now.